# Workaround for missing migrate-deregister command in Drush 10.3.1?

Tags: 8, drush, migrations

I'm trying to migrate and upgrade a site from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8 (version 8.9.1). The migration cannot be accomplished with the UI, since I need to make some changes to the content types and taxonomies during the process. I followed the advice at https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrade-using-drush and generated individual migrations using `drush migrate-upgrade --configure-only` so that I could use the YAML files it generates as the basis for a custom migration module.

After I built my module, I ran `drush migrate-status` (alias `drush ms`). I can see that my migrations are registered, but the ones generated earlier by `drush migrate-upgrade` are also there. In the past, removing them would be a simple matter of using `drush migrate-deregister` (alias `drush mdreg`), but that command, strangely, is no longer available in the current version of Drush (10.3.1).

How do I deregister the migrations that were generated by `drush migrate-upgrade --configure-only`? I am assuming that if I don't deregister them, my content will be migrated twice, and I don't want that to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those migrations are stored as configuration.
When you run `drush migrate-upgrade --configure-only` the command created various `migrate_plus.migration.*` config data related to your D7 migration.

If you remove the config, you'll remove the migrations. For example:

- If you have config captured in a sync directory, do a `drush cex`, remove all `migrate_plus.migration.*` yml files, then `drush cim`. Drush will drop all migration configuration on import.
- If you'd rather delete the migration directly, `drush cdel` will let you specifically delete a migration.

Even if you delete the migration config, some migration metadata is still kept around in the database (see `migrate_map_` & `migrate_messages_` tables). They'll be re-used if you re-import migration config. If you're finally finished with your migrations, you can delete them.

Comment: Thank you, Shawn! That helps a lot! That information should really be added to the documentation at <https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrade-using-drush>.

Comment: No prob. If you have a d.o. account, I believe you can make suggestions or edit to community documentation.

Comment: I'll edit it after I've successfully completed the migration. Thanks again for your excellent answer!